# Joining 4 tables Using SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hey guys i have 4 tables here and i'm trying to show specific columns to be shown in vb listview with the select statement but i'm having trouble trying to join them.

[Appointment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYwU1.png)

[Doctor Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLj6Z.png)

[Patient Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oqUU.png)

[Staff Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmSLY.png)

The columns that i need are

Doctor Table = **Doctor_Name**

Staff Table = **Staff_Name**

Appointment Table = **Appointment_Date, Appointment_Time**

Patient Table = **First_Name**

Hopefully someone can help me thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT D.Doctor_Name, S.Staff_Name, A.Appointment_Date, A.Appointment_Time, P.First_Name 
FROM APPOINTMENT_TABLE A
INNER JOIN STAFF_TABLE S ON S.STAFF_ID = A.STAFF_ID
INNER JOIN DOCTOR_TABLE D ON D.DOCTOR_ID = A.DOCTOR_ID
INNER JOIN PATIENT_TABLE P ON P.PATIENT_ID = A.PATIENT_ID
```

I think that would do the trick. 
The code itself is quite self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you. you are a life saver